# (Closed) Can't observable search retrieve all data on init in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have been working on a personal app. I want to retrieve all the users data on initialize my component the first time. I couldn't get it work I guess because my `searchTerms` is avoiding my subject string. I've tried to use `this.searchTerms.next('');` in my `onInit` method but no luck. If I type a user name and later remove it, the list of users is shown because the else block for `switchMap` is executed.

**My component:**

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  users: Observable<User[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  getUsers(): void {
    this.users = this.searchTerms
      .debounceTime(300)        // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
      .distinctUntilChanged()   // ignore if next search term is same as previous
      .switchMap(term => term   // switch to new observable each time the term changes
        // return the http search observable
        ? this.userService.search(term)
        // or the observable of all users if there was no search term
        : this.userService.search(''))
      .catch(() => {
        return Observable.of<User[]>([]);
      });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  search(term: string): void {
    // Push a search term into the observable stream.
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }
```

**My template:**

```
...
<h4>User Search</h4>
    <input #userSearchBox id="user-search-box" (keyup)="search(userSearchBox.value)" />
...
<div *ngFor="let user of users | async" class="input-group">
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my problem added the cycle method `ngAfterViewInit` and the following code:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.searchTerms.next('');
}
```

My problem was a timing problem, I was calling the subscribed too soon. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  searchTerm$ = this.searchTerms.asObservable().startWith('');

}
```

Comment: Didn't work. What should I suppose to do with `searchTerm$`?

Comment: you would use it you would use it in all places where you currently use the original subject except for search, that is except for where you use functionality that requires a subject